# field_get_items('user', $user, 'field_name') empty?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities, users

I have a added data to the user using:

```
taxonomy_term_reference
```

when creating the

```
field_create_instance($instance)
```

and everything is working fine, I can add and store values and these are added to the specified vocabulary.

The problem is, I cannot extract the value added as a term to the $user object using field_get_items and field_view_value since field_get_items('user', $user, 'field_name') is empty.

Is field_get_items and field_view_value not applicable to $user?

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing the same issue. field_get_items was always empty when trying to get a field attached to a user. The problem was that the $user object you get when you do a

`global $user`

isn't the full entity. So when you pass it into the field_get_items function, it doesn't match anything.

Do a full user_load on the $user->uid and THEN pass the resulting object to field_get_items, and everything should work.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, I did var_dump the entire $user and could see it wasn't complete, and field_get_items does something link $entity->{field_name} so the data if present when field_get_items is called